# I get "ERROR: In --require-hashes mode, all requirements must have their versions pinned with ==" when I do "pip install -r requirements"

Tags: pip, python-3.6, requirements.txt

I get following message at the bottom of cmd line when I try to install some requirements with python 3.6.8 to my folder using "pip install -r requirements.txt"

```
ERROR: In --require-hashes mode, all requirements must have their versions pinned with ==. These do not:
    importlib-metadata from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/71/c2/cb1855f0b2a0ae9ccc9b69f150a7aebd4a8d815bd951e74621c4154c52a8/importlib_metadata-4.8.1-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=b618b6d2d5ffa2f16add5697cf57a46c76a56229b0ed1c438322e4e95645bd15 (from backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.0->-r requirements-38.txt (line 7))
```

I already update my pip version to 21.2.4,
Does anyone know what might cause and how to solve this?
Appreciate!!

Comment: Some people report that this is **because of** pip 21, and `pip install pip==20.2.4` fixes it.

Comment: Any solution with pip 22? Can we just change requirements.txt/Pipfile somehow to fix that?

Comment: [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75729749/getting-error-in-require-hashes-mode-all-requirements-must-have-their-versi)

Answer (score 0):

Working fine after changing pip version from 21 to 20.2.4

Comment: This is likely a pip problem so try out different versions and finally found 1 that works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these solutions:

1. `pip install --no-deps -r requirements.txt` which will prevent pip to look for dependencies at the installation time.
2. `pip install --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver -r requirements.txt` to use the legacy dependency resolver.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75729749/getting-error-in-require-hashes-mode-all-requirements-must-have-their-versi)