# Getting "ERROR: In --require-hashes mode, all requirements must have their versions pinned with"

Tags: pip, python-3.8, requirements.txt, pip-compile

I want to use SHA256 hashes for installing pip packages and I have all dependencies pinned in `requirements.in` like this

```
apache-beam[gcp]==2.38.0
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
bleach==4.1.0
certifi==2021.5.30
deepdiff==5.8.1
defusedxml==0.7.1
elasticsearch==7.17.0
firebase-admin==5.2.0
future==0.18.2
googledatastore==7.0.2
google-cloud-storage==2.1.0
google-auth==1.35.0
google-cloud-dataflow-client==0.3.1
google-cloud-logging==3.0.0
google-cloud-ndb==1.11.1
google-cloud-secret-manager==2.12.4
google-cloud-tasks==2.7.2
google-cloud-translate==3.6.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
html5lib==1.1
mailchimp3==3.0.15
mutagen==1.45.1
pillow==9.0.1
pylatexenc==2.10
pytest==6.2.5
PyYAML==6.0
redis==3.5.3
requests==2.26.0
requests-mock==1.9.3
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
result==0.6.0
rsa==4.7.2
simplejson==3.17.5
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.3.1
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
urllib3==1.26.7
webapp2==3.0.0b1
webencodings==0.5.1
```

FYI, I am using
pip 22.1.1, python 3.8.15 and pip-compile 6.6.2.
To generate hash, I used `pip-compile --generate-hashes  requirements.in` and then `pip install --require-hashes -r requirements.txt` to enable hash verification. But I am getting error like this:

```
ERROR: In --require-hashes mode, all requirements must have their versions pinned with ==. These do not:
    google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.22.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/24/a17e75c733609dce285a2dae6f56837d69a9566963c9d1cab96d788546c8/google_api_core-2.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (from firebase-admin==5.2.0->-r requirements.txt (line 179))
```

Please help me to understand the reason of this error and how to resolve it. Thanks

I am expecting to install the dependencies(with hash verification) without any error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It still seems like an issue with pip and I found [this](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9644) issue exactly stating what I am trying to point out. In those error logs of my question, pip installed the latest version of `google-api-core` when the version was already pinned. It's more likely because of that extra `grpc`.

Two solutions worked for me.

1. Using `--no-deps` which will prevent pip to look for dependencies at the installation time. I think it makes sense since dependencies are already resolved while generating the requirements file. The command will be

> pip install --require-hashes --no-deps -r requirements.txt

2. Using `--use-deprecated=legacy-resolver` option and the command will be

> pip install --require-hashes --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver -r
> requirements.txt

Answer (score 0):

Alternative workaround: just add the indirect dependency to be a direct dependency.

For example, given the error

```
ERROR: In --require-hashes mode, all requirements must have their versions pinned with ==. These do not:
    aiohttp>=3.7.4 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/8d/769a1e9cdce1c9774dd2edc8f4e94c759256246066e5263de917e5b22a0a/aiohttp-3.9.1-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (from black==23.12.0->-r docs/rtd_requirements.txt (line 22))
```

It gets solved by just running

1. `pip install aiohttp`

   - If you're using poetry, then it's `poetry add aiohttp`

Source: [this](https://github.com/alphanome-ai/sec-parser/commit/e6b9a1b53fa8114d7dcaac8029b1fb286e2b543e#diff-50c86b7ed8ac2cf95bd48334961bf0530cdc77b5a56f852c5c61b89d735fd711R75) fixed [that](https://readthedocs.org/projects/sec-parser/builds/22868261/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think this will apply only if sometime wants or already using poetry.

Comment: @Sujay Thanks! This fix should still apply to `pip`. Updated the answer